# Command Line tool for Linux to test Windows Radius

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, radius, windows-ias-server

Anyone know a tool that works to test authentication against a Windows Radius Server?

I have tried [`radtest`](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jump?q=radtest) with:

```
radtest -d /usr/share/freeradius/ kbrandt 'betYouCantGuess' theServer 10 secretIGaveforMyIP 0 192.168.254.82
```

But I get:

```
Sending Access-Request of id 120 to 192.168.254.253 port 1812
    User-Name = "kbrandt"
    User-Password = "betYouCantGuess"
    NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.254.82
    NAS-Port = 10
    Framed-Protocol = PPP
rad_recv: Access-Reject packet from host 192.168.254.253 port 1812, id=120, length=20
```

On the server in the log there is:

```
192.168.254.82,kbrandt,11/06/2009,10:38:28,IAS,THESERVER,4,192.168.254.82,5,10,7,1,4108,192.168.254.82,4116,0,4128,Kyle's Workstation,4155,1,4154,Use Windows authentication for all users,4129,MYDOMAIN\kbrandt,4127,1,4149,Connections to other access servers,25,311 1 192.168.254.253 11/06/2009 15:32:42 4,4130,mydomain.com/Users/Kyle Brandt,4136,1,4142,0
192.168.254.82,kbrandt,11/06/2009,10:38:28,IAS,THESERVER,25,311 1 192.168.254.253 11/06/2009 15:32:42 4,4130,mydomain.com/Users/Kyle Brandt,4149,Connections to other access servers,4108,192.168.254.82,4116,0,4128,Kyle's Workstation,4155,1,4154,Use Windows authentication for all users,4129,MYDOMAIN\kbrandt,4127,1,4136,3,4142,66
```

I'm new to Radius, so its possible I haven't configured something right. All I did was install the service, and added my ip as a RADIUS Client using Radius-Standard Vendor.

Comment: Maybe I need to add a Remote Access Policy (The defaults are not enough)?

Comment: Also, any tool that tells me what all those fields in the IAS log mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working, I removed the policies that were there.  Then added one for a group I am in, and also had to add PAP authentication.  More information on why I was denied was available in the Event Viewer.

Comment: You should read up on Remote Access Policies. They're a little bit counter-intuitive, but you can do some really cool stuff with them.

Comment: Evan: Ya, trying to find something short and to the point.  I think with this little project of mine (I think you get the idea from my recent posts), is that all I want is authentication, and the router would handle the rest.  Does that seem right?

Comment: There are a lot of features of Remote Access Policies you won't be using in a RADIUS situation, so knowing how the policies are evaluated and applied is probably the gist of what you need to know.